# Help with Time Complexity

Tags: time-complexity, python

Suppose we have the function below:

```
def func(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n - i):
            for k in range(n - j):
                if i + j + k == 0:
                    break
            if i + j == 0:
                break
        if i == 0:
            break
    return n + 1
```

We have three nested for-loops and the total number of elements evaluated appears to be: (n)(n-1)(n-2). However, this cannot be correct, as I know the time complexity of this function is not O(n^3). What is the proper way to evaluate the time complexity of this function?

Comment: Could you please rewrite your code as pseudocode so people don't have to understand what the `range` command does in Python?

Comment: also, put eval() function to where it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function has constant running time (or linear running time, depending on how `range` is implemented). I suggest running it step-by-step and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for Python 3.0 then by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3) knowledge;

- Your function is constant time $\mathcal{O}(1)$. Since every loop runs once end finishes.

If Python version < 3.0;

```
def func(n):
    for i in range(n):             #generates all the numbers at once 
        for j in range(n - i):     #generates all the numbers at once 
            for k in range(n - j): #generates all the numbers at once 
                if i + j + k == 0:
                    break
                else:
                    eval()
            if i + j == 0:
                break
        if i == 0:
            break
    return n + 1
```

- Since each loop actually runs once the result will be $\mathcal{O}(n)$ assuming that your `eval` function is in $\mathcal{O}(n)$.

Comment: If `range n` generates the whole set $\{0, \dots, n\}$ before running the loop, then constructing that set will take linear time.

Comment: Actually, `range(n)` should generate the set $0,\ldots,n-1$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus depend on the python version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081275/why-is-1000000000000000-in-range1000000000000001-so-fast-in-python-3